# Kernel panic when OC RAM or turning on additional fan

Tags: boot, 20.04, system

I have old pc which uses DDR2 ram, so i wanted to change freq from 667 to 800 MHz, but Ubuntu won't boot due to Kernel panic. The same issue i have when i turn on additional fan to keep pc cooler, but sometimes system will boot, but freezes on about 5 minutes. I am not using any custom kernels.

PC specs:
CPU: Core 2 Quad Q6600
RAM: 8 GB DDR2 667 MHz (4 x 2 GB)
GPU: ATI Radeon HD 4650
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS

Comment: This sounds like more of a hardware issue than an OS-specific problem, most likely related to power issues. If you are receiving a kernel panic, then you will have logs and/or something specific on the screen saying what the panic was triggered by. Please [edit] your question to include this information so that it might be possible to offer some solutions 

Comment: Obviously... don't overclock your CPU or RAM.

Comment: Strange, now when i overclocked ram and turned on fan, the pc boots

Answer (score 0):

I set this error as temporary fixed, because changed PSU from Logic 500W to Modecom FEEL 3 400W and looking at least for the temp of both, the first one might be broken.